# Prevent Screen from creating sub shells

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I'm running a Linux system that starts a custom text mode application from the .bashrc. The users are getting disconnected due to network dropouts.

I had the idea that I'd use screen to allow them to get back to the prior session, but I like to make sure that they can't open a subshell that allows access to the UNIX command line (or for that matter, another login).

I've modified .screenrc with the following:
    bind c
    bind ^c

To prevent the Control-A Control-C command from working. Are are any other security issues that I need to be a where of here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to prevent users from doing `C-a : shell` as well, and probably many other commands. Look into screen acl commands. Start with `aclchg $USER -x ?` and enable the commands you see fit.